# In a Tiddler, how to list all its fields and their values?

Tags: tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

Using TiddlyWiki, I'm trying to show, in a specific Tiddler, a subset of all the fields of that tiddler, with their values.

The problem is, while I'm able to list all the relevant fields' names, I cannot print their value.

My current code is:

```
<$list filter="[fields[]prefix[Result_]sort[title]]"  template="$:/zx/ListFieldItemTemplate"/>
```

... which aims to list all the fields starting with `Result_`.

The (simplified) template `$:/zx/ListFieldItemTemplate` is:

```
<div>
    <$view field="title"/>
</div>
```

My fear is that the list widget is only sending the names of the fields, not the values, which means there's no way to get that value from the template. So I may need to somehow send the values, too. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use a macro.

In your tiddler, put the following macro call:

```
<<myMacro prefix:"Result_">>
```

(The aim is to filter the fields only to those starting with "Result_".)

Then, create a new tiddler, whose name is not important, but which must contain the tag `$:/tags/Macro` to make that macro globally available. And in that tiddler, write the following code:

```
\define myMacro(prefix:"")
<$list filter="[fields[]prefix[$prefix$]sort[title]]" variable="fieldName">
<<fieldName>>
====
<$view field=<<fieldName>>/>
</$list>
\end
```

This will output something like:

```
Result_MyFieldName1 ==== MyFieldValue1
Result_MyFieldName2 ==== MyFieldValue2
Result_MyFieldName3 ==== MyFieldValue3
Result_MyFieldName4 ==== MyFieldValue4
```

Of course, you can then modify the macro to use your own formatting.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but maybe someone will find this useful:

Loop through all fields and list name/value:

<$list filter="[fields[]] -[[title]] -[[text]] -[[tags]] -[[created]] -[[modified]]" variable="fieldname">
<> = <$view field=<> />
</$list>